# U-SQL + Python basic questions

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am just getting started learning how to integrate Python with U-SQL. I am working through this example:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [ExtPython];

DECLARE @myScript = @"
def get_mentions(tweet):    
      return ';'.join( ( w[1:] for w in tweet.split() if w[0]=='@' ) )

def usqlml_main(df):    
      del df['time']    
      del df['author']    
      df['mentions'] = df.tweet.apply(get_mentions)    
      del df['tweet']    
      return df
";

@t  =     
SELECT * FROM        
(VALUES
           ("D1","T1","A1","@foo Hello World @bar"),
           ("D2","T2","A2","@baz Hello World @beer")
       ) AS
            D( date, time, author, tweet );
@m  =
    REDUCE @t ON date
    PRODUCE date string, mentions string
    USING new Extension.Python.Reducer(pyScript:@myScript);

OUTPUT @m
    TO "/tweetmentions.csv"
    USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Inside of usqlml_main, what is the 'apply' function in df.tweet.apply(get_mentions)?

Also, what does REDUCE do in this case? Is this always needed when integrating U-SQL with Python?

Answer (score 4):

#### Q: How does usqlml_main take in a dataframe? Is D(date, time, author, tweet) constructing a pandas dataFrame?

When the rowset @t is used by Extension.Python.Reducer, the rows will be placed into a pandas dataFrame.

#### Q: Inside of usqlml_main, what is the 'apply' function in df.tweet.apply(get_mentions)?

This is the pandas apply() method that is defined on DataFrames: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

#### Q: What does REDUCE do in this case? Is this always needed when integrating U-SQL with Python?

REDUCE is needed. Its name "REDUCE" is misleading in this context. The purpose of REDUCE in the U-SQL/Python context is that REDUCE is used to distribute a large set of rows into smaller partitions based on a key value that comes from a specific column. In the example above it is trying to partition on the date column. REDUCE does not imply that the code actually has to return a "reduced" set of rows. In fact the reduce could return even more rows. Again, it's more about data partitioning.

Comment: I am using U-SQL+Python for Text processing. I have set parallelism to 25 but at the point where python code is executing only one vertex is running in parallel. Is there a way to improve it ? Where can i find the details on how to achieve parallelism ?